# Show that $ \frac{2e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{1 - e^{-2\lambda}} = \frac{1}{1+e^\lambda} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm told that 
$$
\frac{2e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})}{1 - e^{-2\lambda}} = \frac{2}{1+e^\lambda}
$$
holds for any real $\lambda > 0$, but I just cannot see it. Is there any property I'm missing here or am I just being thick?

Comment: Start with the fact that

$$1 - e^{-2\lambda} = (1 - e^{-\lambda})(1 + e^{-\lambda})$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factorise the bottom as the difference of two squares, cancel the common factor, and multiply top and bottom by $e^{\lambda}$